# Using anonymous function in class constructor and using in method

Tags: php, class, methods, constructor

I am trying to use anonymous function in the constructor , to assign it to a public variable and then using that variable in methods.

**My Class**

```
class siteAnalytics {
    public $db_count;                                           // FUNCTION "$db_count" - CALLED FROM "FUNCTIONS.PHP"
    public $db_sum;                                             // FUNCTION "$db_sum" - CALLED FROM "FUNCTIONS.PHP"
    public $db_readAll;                                         // FUNCTION "$db_readAll" - CALLED FROM "FUNCTIONS.PHP"

    public function __construct($db_count, $db_sum, $db_readAll) {
        $this->db_count   = $db_count;
        $this->db_sum     = $db_sum;
        $this->db_readAll = $db_readAll;
    }

    public function siteData(){
        // CREATE "SITE DATA" ARRAY FROM QUERIES
        $SD_array = array(
            'U_active'       => $this->db_count("users", "*", "WHERE a_status='true'"),
        );
    }
}
```

**Call to Class**

```
$siteAnalytics = new siteAnalytics($db_count, $db_sum, $db_readAll);
print_r($siteAnalytics->siteData());
```

**What is the error?**

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method siteAnalytics::db_count()

**I am getting the error, in the `siteData()` method in the array where `$this->db_count` is getting called !**

**I know i can pass anonymous functions through the methods but why it is not working while passing through the constructor.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to assign a property to a local variable and then call it like a function:

```
public function siteData(){
    $db_count = $this->db_count;
    // CREATE "SITE DATA" ARRAY FROM QUERIES
    $SD_array = array(
        'U_active'       => $db_count("users", "*", "WHERE a_status='true'"),
    );
}
```

**Update:**
You can try to surround your property retrieving with a pair of parentheses:

```
public function siteData(){
    // CREATE "SITE DATA" ARRAY FROM QUERIES
    $SD_array = array(
        'U_active'       => ($this->db_count)("users", "*", "WHERE a_status='true'"),
    );
}
```